# Display ACF custom fields on WooCommerce store home and category listing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to display Advanced Custom Field on my WooCommerce storefront in html list tag. I modified the file:

```
content-product_cat.php
```

from this:

```
<li <?php wc_product_cat_class( '', $category ); ?>>
```

to this:

```
<li style="background: <?php the_field('my_ACF_field'); ?>" <?php wc_product_cat_class( '', $category ); ?>>
```

And also I added ACF field on my WP backend and assigned it to my page called "Store" which is the WooCommerce storefront. I can fill the input on my backend (Store page) but it's not showing on storefront/category page, it's just not passing. Where is the problem?

I also tried to set this field as taxonomy, and display it on category setting in WooCommerce, also without success.

Comment: Category page is not the store page. Maybe add the acf field to WC product categories.

Comment: Also without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to use the second parameter on ACF the_field, to get the value for the specific object that you're after. E.g. if you have the ACF Field set on a product category, you'll need to pass in the term that you're currently looking at to get the right value.

I believe that on a category page you'll need to use something like

```
<li style="background: <?php the_field('my_ACF_field', $category);?>" <?php wc_product_cat_class( '', $category ); ?>>
```

This ACF documentation field gives more detail about adding fields to taxonomy terms: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/

Comment: Thank you! This work work me, but is it possible to change this code to put ACF fields in "Store" page not in WooCommerce category settings?

Comment: Try passing in the page post_id as the second parameter. I'm not quite clear where you're trying to use the ACF field on the shop page though. The documentation for the ACF the_field function might help? https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/

Comment: OK I made it with by adding variable `$post_id = 61;` to my `content-product_cat.php` and changed $category to $post_id but still try to figure out how to do it the same in functions.php file

Comment: What are you trying to do with it in functions.php? Try using get_field instead if you want to use the value in a variable. Again, from the ACF documentation: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/